# Positive integer solutions to $x_1+...+x_n=k$.

Tags: combinatorics

> What is the number of strictly positive integer solutions
>   $(x_1,...,x_n)$ to the equation $x_1+...+x_n=k$?

Say $n=3$ and $k=5$, then we have $x_1+x_2+x_3=5$. It's easy to find that the number of solutions to this equation is $6$.

This is a standard placing $5$ people on $3$ chairs problem, with respect to order. So why isn't the answer simply ${5\choose 3}$, or in the general case of placing $k$ people on $n$ chairs ${k\choose n}$? Why do I have to subtract the $1$?

Comment: How is it the problem of putting five people in three chair? What does that even mean, to put $5$ people in three chairs?

Comment: It means comunism.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews In how many ways can you pick 3 people out of five. Basic combinatorics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A particular solution of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = k $$
in the positive integers corresponds to the placement of $n - 1$ addition signs in the $k - 1$ spaces between successive ones in a row of $k$ ones.  Thus, the equation has
$$\binom{k - 1}{n - 1}$$
solutions in the positive integers.

Consider your example.  If we wish to find the number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 5$$
we must decide which two of the four spaces between successive ones in a row of five ones will be filled with addition signs.
$$1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1$$
For instance, if we fill the second and fourth spaces with addition signs, we obtain
$$1 1 + 1 1 + 1$$
which corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 2$, $x_2 = 2$, and $x_3 = 1$.  Observe that there are $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ such choices, as you found.

Comment: I don't understand why there will wlays be $k-1$ spaces in between the ones?

Comment: If there are $k$ ones, there are $k - 1$ spaces between successive ones.  Consider the example with $5$ ones.  There are $5 - 1 = 4$ spaces between successive ones.

Comment: Oh, yes ofcourse. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Think of it like this, for $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\geq 0$. $$x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n=k\tag{1}$$

Means that you have a line of $k$ elements, and you want to divide the line into $n$ sections.

For $x_1+x_2+x_3=5$ it may look like this: $$\times|\times\times|\times\times$$

You have $5+3-1$ empty places, and you need to choose which one of them is are $\times$'s (the rest will be $|$'s). There are $\binom{5+3-1}{5}$ ways to accomplish this. In the general there are $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$ ways.

---

Edit: If you want $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n> 0$ you can let $x_i=y_i+1$, where $y_i\geq 0$. You can then rewrite equation (1) as:

$$y_1+y_2+\dots+y_n=k-n$$

Comment: See also: [Wiki: stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: @Arthur You're right, I have updated my answer. Thank you!

Comment: How can you see that I have $5+3-1$ empty spaces? What do you mean by an empty space?

Comment: By "empty space" i mean a "place" where you can place a symbol. If you removed the $\times$'s and $|$'s you would have _ _ _ _ _ _ _, which is what i call $7$ empty spaces.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> By definition:

\begin{align}
\sum_{x_{1} = 1}^{\infty}\cdots\sum_{x_{n} = 1}^{\infty}
\bracks{z^{k}}z^{x_{1} + \cdots + x_{n}} & =
\bracks{z^{k}}\pars{\sum_{x = 1}^{\infty}z^{x}}^{n} =
\bracks{z^{k}}\pars{z \over 1 - z}^{n} = \bracks{z^{k - n}}\pars{1 - z}^{-n}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{k - n \geq 0}{-n \choose k - n}\pars{-1}^{k - n} =
\bbx{\bracks{k \geq n}{k - 1 \choose k - n}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\bracks{k \geq n}{k - 1 \choose n - 1}}
\end{align}

> *Your example*: $\ds{n = 3}$ and $\ds{k = 5}$ yields $\ds{{5 - 1 \choose 3 - 1} = {4 \choose 2} = \color{red}{6}}$.

Comment: This solution makes use of [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function).

Comment: @N.F.Taussig It's true. It's a straightforward way. Thanks.